# Emulator Admob ad

Tags: android, admob

I accidentally clicked my ad in the emulator (not a test ad) and my app is linked with AdMob.  Will anything be shut down for false reporting of ad impression and clicks?  Like my application is not in google play just yet, I am still testing things out in the emulator.  Is this something to really worry about or no not really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en):

"Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods. Testing your own ads by clicking on them is not allowed.

Google treats invalid activity very seriously, analyzing all clicks and impressions to determine whether they fit a pattern of use that might artificially drive up an advertiser's costs or a publisher's earnings. If we determine that an AdMob account might pose a risk to our advertisers, we may disable that account to protect our advertisers' interests."

You don't have to worry if you only clicked once or twice. However, multiple clicks even when done unintentionally would be detected and treated as clicks generated with malicious or fraudulent intent aka [click fraud](https://www.google.com/ads/adtrafficquality/#click-fraud-and-invalid-traffic) which leads to disabling of associated accounts.

No safety threshold has been given so to be on a safe side just make sure you test via test ads. You only need one line of code to so :

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) //Remove this line after testing
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you..I just checked out the AdMob site and my app (not on google play just yet) has 247 impressions and earnings total is $0.00 but today earnings (from one click) is $0.06.  I had the real ads running in the emulator when testing it and didnt think to turn them off or into test ads.  Ugh I hope they dont disable my account/app for this..

Comment: ok good, thanks again. I wont worry.  I have been working quite hard on my app and I am almost done :)